# iOS 7 : Get accurate type of rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard

I have `set InitViewController` as an initial view controller in `storyboard`. I am trying to get the root view controller using following expression:

```
UIViewController *initViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

Sometimes initViewController is of type InitViewController and sometimes it is 
`_UIModalItemAppViewController`. I am not able to figure out why type of initViewController changes to `_UIModalItemAppViewController`. I want `initViewController` always to be of type `InitViewController`. Please help.

Comment: Are you presenting an alert view or action sheet?

Comment: Yes. I am presenting an alert view during app launch. At the same time I want to get initViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are presenting an alert view on application launch the alert view is presented modally and apparently taking over the root position. Grabbing a reference to the root view controller before presenting the alert view should resolve the issue. I'd note, however, that you might want to consider whether it is appropriate to present an alert view in the place you are presenting it (sounds like didFinishLaunching in app delegate?)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @bgfriend0..!! I just placed alert view in viewDidLoad method of InitViewController and got rid of problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. Here is one last thing to consider. If you are very intent on presenting this alertView right away, you may want to move it from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear. viewDidLoad is not always the best place to put UI stuff, because remember that a view can be loaded without being presented at all. In this particular case there is probably not going to be much of a practical difference, especially since your doing a modal presentation--it would be more of a design improvement.